# Update C# form RichTextBox content (in realtime) with the output of the batch file execution without waiting for the batch command execution to finish

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-forms-designer

Below is my C# code in the form.

```
    private void callInfraCommand(string cmd)
    {
        string os_name = GetOSFriendlyName();
        var m_command = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        // set up output redirection
        m_command.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        m_command.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        m_command.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        m_command.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        m_command.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        m_command.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        m_command.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // see below for output handler
        m_command.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
        m_command.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

        if (os_name.Contains("Windows 7") || os_name.Contains("2008") || os_name.Contains("Windows 8") || os_name.Contains("2012"))
            m_command.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        else
            m_command.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINNT\system32\cmd.exe";

        m_command.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        m_command.Start();

        m_command.BeginErrorReadLine();
        m_command.BeginOutputReadLine();
        m_command.WaitForExit();
    }

    private void proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // output will be in string e.Data
        if (e.Data != null)
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => deploy_result_txt.Text += (Environment.NewLine + e.Data)));
    }
```

I am passing the windows batch file to `callInfraComamnd` and it's block of code is working fine. But, my batch file is taking more than 5 minutes to finish and during that time, my form is freezing and after the batch process completes it displaying all the output of the batch file in chunk.

Ideally, i would like to see the progress (intermediate output of the batch file) in the `TextBox` while the batch process is running in the background.

Can anyone please advise how can I resolve it (i am using .NET 4) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the content of `private void callInfraCommand(string cmd)` in a `Task`. The `m_command.WaitForExit()` blocks the thread calling this function (the UI thread). Since it's blocked it cannot process the marshalled code in `proc_DataReceived()` before `m_command.WaitForExit()` finished.

Option 1: don't wait for exit which would block the UI thread
    private void callInfraCommand(string cmd)
    {
        //...

```
    m_command.BeginErrorReadLine();
    m_command.BeginOutputReadLine();
    // m_command.WaitForExit();
}
```

Option 2: Call the blocking part in a separate task

```
private void callInfraCommand(string cmd)
{
    //...

    m_command.BeginErrorReadLine();
    m_command.BeginOutputReadLine();


    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => 
            {
                m_command.WaitForExit()
                // code to clean up etc.
                // if there is nothing in here, there's no need to call WaitForExit()!
            }
    );
}
```

UPDATE:
Option 3: Do something after the process finished which is defined elsewhere.

```
private void callInfraCommand(string cmd, Action afterFinishedAction)
{
    //...

    m_command.BeginErrorReadLine();
    m_command.BeginOutputReadLine();


    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => 
            {
                m_command.WaitForExit()

                afterFinishedAction();
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my requirement, I do need to do some other work after command execute successfully. after using your code my form is not freezing but my code is not able to know if the process has finished in the background or not. I am suppose to do other depended work/process after the successful execution of the command execution. Is there anyway, i can check if the process has finished successfully ?

Comment: @Sam Use option 2 and put the stuff in the task. Just beware that you might need to marshal stuff if you access UI variables/controls.

Comment: Is there a way I can track the task completion status from other part of the code ??

Comment: @Sam See updated Option 3. You can now add an `Action`, e.g. a lambda function defined elsewhere and execute it afte the process finished. You may use an `Action<WhateverTypeYourActionMightDepend>` if the action needs data from this method (e.g. an `Action<int>` if you need the exit code from the process).

Comment: Thanks Onur. Options you are provided are really helpful. In my case, I am having trouble handling the thread where WaitForExit() is working. I have series of batch commands which needs to be executed after the successful execution of the first command. I am trying to find a way to track the thread where I am running WaitForExit().

Answer (score 0):

@Sam Then I suggest you create a task which contains the loop over each process call and leave the waitForExit.